# How to increase clang parsing performance using PCH or PTH?

Tags: c++, clang, pch, pth

I'm using Clang C API for parsing and getting diagnostics. I've noticed that i'm using the same bundle of headers all the time, so i've decided to try to use PCH or PTH to increase performance.

But i'm getting diagnostics that neither PCH nor PTH were used while `clang_parseTranslationUnit`:

- argument unused during compilation: '-emit-pth'
- /tmp/system/include/libcxx/iostream.pth: 'linker' input unused
- argument unused during compilation: '-emit-pch'
- /tmp/system/include/libcxx/iostream.pch: 'linker' input unused

I'm surprised that PCH and PTH were not used while parsing, so how can i use PCH or PTH or any other approach to increase parsing performance?

PS.

PTH was generated using `clang++ -x c++-header iostream -emit-pth -o iostream.pth`, PCH in similar way

**Update 1:**

I've found [PCH usage example](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html):

```
// This will load all the symbols from 'IndexTest.c', excluding symbols
// from 'IndexTest.pch'.
char *args[] = { "-Xclang", "-include-pch=IndexTest.pch" };
TU = clang_createTranslationUnitFromSourceFile(Idx, "IndexTest.c", 2, args, 0, 0);
```

The problem is that now i'm getting another diagnostics warning:

```
'-pch=/system/include/libcxx/iostream.pch' file not found
```

Looks like command-line arguments were parsed incorrectly.. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: not working for me either

Answer (score 0):

One needs to include `-Xclang` before each argument:

```
char *args[] = { "-Xclang", "-include-pch", "-Xclang", "IndexTest.pch" };
```

See https://reviews.llvm.org/diffusion/L/browse/cfe/trunk/test/Index/c-index-pch.c for inspiration.